# Различия "poisonous" и "venomous"

Tags: значение-слов

В английском языке есть вполне чёткое различие для понятий "poisonous" и "venomous". А есть ли в русском языке такое различие?

Или и грибы, и змеи будут просто "ядовитые"?

Comment: In russian we have отравляющие и ядовитые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И змеи, и грибы *ядовитые*.
См. словарь:

> Ядовитый - содержащий яд, вызывающий отравление. // Выделяющий яд. // разг. Причиняющий вред здоровью человека.

Возможно, стоит добавить, что *venomous* может переводиться как ядовитый в значении "язвительный, ехидный, злобный".